# Writing to function pointer

Tags: c, memory

Why do the following 2 (simplified) examples segfault (compiled with GCC under Win7)?

**Case 1- Writing to a function pointer**

```
void f() {return;}
int main()
{
  memcpy(&f, "", 1);
  return 0;
}
```

**Case 2 - Calling a data pointer**

```
char f[] ={0xC3};
typedef void(*p)();
int main()
{
  ((p)f)();
  return 0;
}
```

I know it is because I am writing a RO section of memory and jumping to a non-executable section of memory. (or something like that). My question is "Why" in the big-picture sense:
What system exactly enforces this? Is it at the OS level? At the HW level? At the HW level but needs to be set up by the OS when loading the binary into memory? What subsystem does this? etc...

Maybe "How" would be a better question than "Why".

Comment: [**W⊕X**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)

Comment: If you're on a PC or Mac platform, it's enforced by the operating system since you don't normally write code that puts things into flash (not with the typical app development tools anyway). Various embedded systems may be designed with some HW enforcement. But generally, it's the OS.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7220675 http://stackoverflow.com/q/10183110 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3828358

Answer (score 0):

For Windows this is enforced at the OS level by page protections. Each page has assigned to it a set of protection flags specifying what its characteristics are (readable, writable, executable, guard page, etc.). The page protection can be changed with [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after which you will be able to write to the code pages.

Under the covers having code not being executable may be supported by hardware such as the NX flag which is essentially what `VirtualProtect` is toggling.

Answer (score 0):

On x86 platforms it's implemented in hardware: The CPU divides the memory into pages (usually 4kb in size on 32-bit platforms) each with various access bits (though the Execute access flag wasn't actually supported until relatively late).

Page information is itself stored in tables in memory; the CPU just keeps a register pointing to the master table, and probably some cached contents as well.

At OS level, the OS sets the corresponding table pointers during each context switch (and changes the flag values during system calls that allocate memory), so the CPU always know which pages the current process can access.